# Compilation of library in C++

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, codeblocks

The question appeared when I was trying to install SFML (Simple and Fast Multimedia Library for c++) on codeblocks Mgw32 on my Thinkpad2 tablet. I did everything according to instructions from SFML web page. Then I copied and *successfully compiled* test code (simple code that creates window and draws circle) from the same instructions.

However code always was crashing during the run time (I was getting usual windows crash report saying that something went wrong in msvcrt.dll). I figured out that it crashed when sf::RenderWindow instance was created. All SMFL functions before sf::RenderWindow was working properly.

I checked web and read that some people managed to solve same problem (compiles but crashes during runtime) by compiling SFML by codeblocks on their computers. And here comes something that I want to understand: *what is the difference between library that was downloaded already in compiled form for particular OS and particular coding environment that is used by user and library that was compiled by user?* Does compilation by user adjust code for software and hardware that user uses? If so then to what extent and will (or rather how will) this compiled code run on different hardware with the same OS?

I feel that question is very broad (it's because I have very limited knowledge in the area) so I don't expect precise answer all that I want is just some hit that can point direction where I should look for answer.

Comment: _I feel that question is very broad_ Yes it is, and that may merely make it off-topic and closed.

Comment: _Perhaps_ your question isn't that broad, but it's __very long__ and it may make some people skip it

Comment: The number of possibilities is staggering. Low hanging fruit is the canned library is compiled against windows libraries that have been updated and their behaviour altered. Recommend using building a debug load of your software and taking advantage of code::block's gdb debugging support to try and narrow your question to something like, It crashes after I make this call with these parameters and the following configuration.

Comment: So the question really is: *What is the difference between pre built  binaries and binaries compiled from source by the end user?* You could have just asked that to increase the chance of someone answering. Although not sure if it still is too broad...